# Change 'src' attribute of images by AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to change `src` attribute of image by ajax request,

```
$.ajax({

   url: "/l/"+id1,
   type: "get", 
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (data) {
    $data = $(data);

    $("#like" + id1).attr("src",$data");

            }
        });
```

Response is something like `/uploads/like.png`

Without `dataType: "json"` , I receive error:

`Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /uploads/like.png`

(So Ajax works and response is received) ,  after adding `dataType:"json"` error gone but nothing more happens.

HTML part (produced by server):

(every image has different `id1`, e.q `id1=33` , so response goes to each selected image.)

```
<img id="like33" src="/uploads/default.png" />
```

Comment: what if you use 'data' directly? what is the point of $(data)?

Comment: You are getting a string back from your AJAX (`/uploads/like.png`).  It is not a selector, and you don't need to use it as a selector, so why use it as a selector `$(data)`? Simply add it as your src attr and you're done.

Comment: @Abolfazl @dont-oanic I worked with this code previously and then i need to work with selectors, you are right. So my current code is  `$("#like" + id1).attr("src",$(data));` but still i cant see difference.

Comment: Are you sure this path ```src="/uploads/default.png"``` is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$.ajax({

url: "/l/"+id1,
type: "get", 
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {
 $("#like" + id1).attr("src", data);

  }
});
```

If you are receiving the string `/uploads/like.png` in the ajax response, you can just pass it into the `attr()` method.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This works but After removing `dataType: "json"` ! tnx anyway.